# White Section between div classes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a web resume and have a profile and experience div classes which are dynamically resized using bootstrap.
See here for a codepen: https://codepen.io/rxestrella/pen/EvORmp
The problem is with the white section under the profile. I have tried adding `display: flex;`
to the profile class but this messes with the bootstrap sizing.
I have also tried
`height:100%;` and `margin:0; padding:0;`

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Comment: Will do this the next time around, this is my second question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this css part if you need changes in responsive part add `media query` like following codepen link.

```
.resume-wrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
```

For responsive.

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  .resume-wrapper {
     display:flex;
     flex-direction:column;
  }
}
```

**[working codepen](https://codepen.io/Lokeshg27/pen/YxdWGw)**

Comment: This definitely solves the problem however I was thinking my problem was using the bootstrap grid system incorrectly. Is this a common problem with divs?